# Strange MySQL 5.7 behavior in LIKE CONCAT

Tags: mysql, collation, mysql-5.7

I am suffering a very strange behavior in Mysql 5.7. It does not happen on 5.6 or 8.0, only 5.7.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion, h.id_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador LIKE CONCAT(r.identificador, '.%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador AND h.id_habitacion = rh.id_habitacion
GROUP BY
    rh.id_reserva_habitacion
```

And this is the minimal dump to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `habitaciones` (
  `id_habitacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_hotel` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_habitacion`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4474 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `habitaciones` (`id_habitacion`, `id_hotel`) VALUES
(1, 200),
(2, 200);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservas` (
  `identificador` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`identificador`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `reservas` (`identificador`, `timestamp`) VALUES
('XXA', '2020-01-02'),
('XXA.01', '2020-01-01'),
('XXB', '2020-01-01');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservas_habitaciones` (
  `id_reserva_habitacion` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identificador` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_habitacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_reserva_habitacion`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `reservas_habitaciones` (`id_reserva_habitacion`, `identificador`, `id_habitacion`) VALUES
(1, 'XXA', 1),
(2, 'XXB', 1),
(3, 'XXB', 2);
```

The query should return the value of 'XXA.01' on the `modificada` field, but it returns NULL.

And now the weird parts:

- If I just remove the `GROUP BY` from the query, it works.

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion, h.id_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador LIKE CONCAT(r.identificador, '.%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador AND h.id_habitacion = rh.id_habitacion
```

- If I just remove the `habitaciones` table from the query, it works.

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador LIKE CONCAT(r.identificador, '.%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador
GROUP BY
    rh.id_reserva_habitacion
```

- If the value of 'XXA.01' was instead 'XXA_01', (and '_%' in the query), it works.`

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion, h.id_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador LIKE CONCAT(r.identificador, '_%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador AND h.id_habitacion = rh.id_habitacion
GROUP BY
    rh.id_reserva_habitacion
```

- If instead of `CONCAT(r.identificador, '.%')` it was `CONCAT('XXA', '.%')`, it works.

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion, h.id_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador LIKE CONCAT('XXA', '.%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador AND h.id_habitacion = rh.id_habitacion
GROUP BY
    rh.id_reserva_habitacion
```

- If I specify a collation (the one it should already have), it works.

```
SELECT
    r.identificador, rh.id_reserva_habitacion, h.id_habitacion,
    (SELECT identificador FROM reservas WHERE identificador COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE CONCAT(r.identificador, '.%') LIMIT 1) AS modificada
FROM
    (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)
WHERE
    r.identificador = 'XXA' AND r.identificador = rh.identificador AND h.id_habitacion = rh.id_habitacion
GROUP BY
    rh.id_reserva_habitacion
```

- If I remove the second record in `habitaciones` leaving only id "1", it also works.
- If I do it in 5.6 or 8.0, it perfectly works (in fact, its been working on 5.6 with no issues)

But at the moment, I cannot accept any of these solutions. Obviously the query and the data are bigger than this example, and I would prefer to not touch any of these.

I think it has something to do with collations or charsets, and the dot in 'XXA.01', but I don't understand how the tables in the query or the number of rows can affect it.

I would like to know if this is about server configuration, tables, fields, charsets, or maybe a bug.

Thanks!

Comment: You should change **FROM  (`reservas` r, `reservas_habitaciones` rh, `habitaciones` h)** to JOIN .. ON ...**

Comment: The result is the same with JOINs

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for both versions.  Consider writing a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .  It is also OK on a couple of versions of MariaDB.